# how to find that key param is in url or not angular js using $location

Tags: angularjs

The url looks something like this

```
file:///Users/tapan/Desktop/untitled%20folder%203/index.html#?page=3&total=20&rank=1&remaning=9&cost=20,000
```

my question is that how to find that the 'key' for example 'rank' is in url or not.

if key 'rank' is in url then don't set key using

```
$location.search('rank', 'angle');
```

otherwise set key using

```
$location.search('rank', 'angle');
```

can anyone provide me the code in controller ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (!$location.search('rank')) {
   $location.search('rank', 'angle');
}
```

Comment: Suggest you improve your answer by specifying what `$location.search(key)` returns. Basically, specify why your code will work.